# Changing variable in instance not working when appending to list - Python

Tags: python, class

Why is this not working as expected (at least for me)? I can't figure why.

```
class Fred:
    def __init__(self):
          self.a=0

fred=Fred()
lista=[]

for i in range(5):
    fred.a=i
    lista.append(fred)

for i in lista:
    print(str(i.a))
```

All I get is 5 times the number 4 and not from 0 to 4. Any comments? 
Thanks

Comment: this is bcoz all the elements in `lista` are referencing to the same element,, and the you see the number 4 since its the latest updated value of the object `fred`

Answer (score 1):

What is happening is that the reference to Fred is being overwritten each time you loop in the `for i in range(5)`. If you move the `fred=Fred()` inside that loop and create a new object each time, then you should see the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

You've got one `Fred` instance and keep adding that one instance to the list, changing its `a` property while you do that. Adding to the list does not copy the `Fred` object; it just adds another reference to the same object. You can get your expected behavior by creating a new `Fred` inside each iteration of the loop.